# Example hawtio plugin monitoring resources via REST

Tags: hawtio

Is there a simple example for a hawtio plugin that monitors resources via REST. I understand hawtio discovers JMX resources via the jolokia REST interace. But I am looking to monitor some resources that don't have a mbean - only a REST API.

I followed the simple plugin at:

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-plugin-examples/simple-plugin/src/main/webapp/plugin/js/simplePlugin.js

and I see how the controller uses the jolokia service:

```
Core.register(jolokia, $scope, {
  type: 'read', mbean: 'java.lang:type=OperatingSystem',
  arguments: []
}, onSuccess(render));
```

Is there a similar example for using a RESTful service?

(PS: new to hawtio and to AngularJS, apologies if this should be obvious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angularjs has $http for doing HTTP/REST calls.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

Also jquery has $ajax

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And if you search the hawtio source code in hawtio-web you can find examples where we use that.

Comment: Also for rest stuff you'd want to use the $resource service in angular, and there's no reason you can't use $resource in a hawtio plugin -> https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/tutorial/step_11.  One thing to note is that hawtio is still on angularjs 1.1.5